# If-Else with nested If in MIPS assembly

Tags: if-statement, assembly, mips

I am trying to code something that continually takes in an integer from the user and stores the minimum value into $s2.

This is a C code representation of what I am trying to do

```
if ( $s2 == 0 )
    $s2 = $t0
else {
    if ( $t0 < $s2 )
    $s2 = $t0
}
```

Basically, I loaded $s2 with zero outside of the input loop. This checks if $s2 has zero, and sets it to the current (first) user input ($t0) since that is the minimum value. If $s2 no longer contains zero then it checks the new user input  against what is already in $s2 and if it is less than it becomes the new minimum value.

How can I implement this in MIPS assembly?

I have this so far (this is the end piece of a loop called read) but all it does is when I press the first int, it skips to the end and prints the min without looping over.

```
read:
    ...

    beq         $s2, $zero, LOAD    

    slt     $s6, $t0, $s2
    bne     $s6, $zero, LOAD

    j       read

LOAD:

    li      $s2, 0
    addu        $s2, $s2, $t0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you need a jump at the bottom of your code because you're [probably] "falling off the edge of the world":

```
 read:
    ...

    beq     $s2,$zero,LOAD

    slt     $s6,$t0,$s2
    bne     $s6,$zero,LOAD

    j       read

LOAD:

    # NOTE: you could use $zero as you did above to eliminate the "li" here
    li      $s2,0
    addu    $s2,$s2,$t0

    # NOTE/BUG: need to jump back to read loop
    j       read
```

---

The code can be shortened a bit.

1. From the `slt` (vs. `sltu`) we know that the values are *signed*. So, if we prefill `$s0` with the maximum positive value (i.e. `0x7FFFFFFF`) instead of zero, we can remove the first `beq` from the loop.
2. Also, if we reverse the sense of the branch after the `slt`, we can eliminate an extra `j` instruction.
3. We can change the `addu` to use `$zero` and eliminate the `li`

---

```
    li      $s2,0x7FFFFFFF          # load maximum positive value

read:
    ...

    slt     $s6,$t0,$s2             # is new value < minimum?
    beq     $s6,$zero,read          # if no, loop

    addu    $s2,$zero,$t0           # save new minimum value
    j       read                    # restart input loop
```